# Angular iframe not working as expected

Tags: angularjs, iframe

I am new to angularjs. I have an angular iframe controller as mentioned below. Please note that this is not actual implementation.

HTML:

```
<div ng-show="showIFrame">   
  <iframe id ="myiframe" ng-src="{{websiteUrl}}"/> 
</div>
```

Controller Directive:

```
directive('iframesample',function(){
    return {
        link:function(scope,ele,attrs){
        var iFrame = element.find("iframe")[0];
        iFrame.onload = function () {
        scope.businesslogic(); //based on current iframe ng-src.
        }
});
```

Issue:

> I am using the iframe controller to display multiple iframes with urls saved in my database. I am calling my businesslogic() on load event of an iframe which is getting called but not in the way I expect to. the businesslogic() (onload event) is not called immediately after the ng-src is set for an iframe. if I display 2 instances of the iframe, upfront the ng-src is set for both iframes and next it will call businesslogic() for each iframe. Due to this, my businesslogic is not applied on second iframe. What should I do to correct this so that my business logic is called as soon as the ng-src is set for an iframe instance.